# Countdown after button click

Tags: vba, excel, countdown

I would like to make a countdown, so I've set a cell, `E1` with time format, and given `0:02:55` as start time. After that I try to make coutdown after button click with this code, but got an error, that it isn't runnable.

```
Sub Timer()
Dim gCount As Date
gCount = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime gCount, "ResetTime"
End Sub

Sub ResetTime()
Dim xRng As Range
Set xRng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("E1")
xRng.Value = xRng.Value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
If xRng.Value <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "Countdown complete."
    Exit Sub
End If
Call Timer
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error code?